# What is the meaning of 'creating answers that can be easily edited by most users'?

Tags: support, answers

To the get the privilege of creating wiki posts you need to do that.
Creating answers is clear but I don't get the meaning of "easily edited by most users".

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> To the get the privilege of creating wiki posts you need to do that.

No. That is just a short description of the privilege. The only requirement is having 10 reputation.
Easily edited means that the answers can be freely edited by users with less reputation than normally (100 instead of 2000).

Comment: So that was just a miss understanding from my side, thank you

Comment: Clarification: normally, there's a review queue for edits people with <2000 reputation, so edits take a while to show up - but are still possible.